# Simple Import of Node Module in Angular 2 with Typings

Tags: angularjs, angular, typescript-typings

The head of my file looks like this:

```
/// <reference path="../../typings/index.d.ts" />
import * as c3 from 'c3';
```

But when I start the app I get this error:

`http://localhost:3000/c3 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)`

c3 is included in package.json dependencies.  typings.json looks like:

```
{
  "globalDependencies": {
    "d3": "registry:dt/d3#0.0.0+20160907005744",
    "c3": "registry:dt/c3#0.0.0+20160926143332",
    "core-js": "registry:dt/core-js#0.0.0+20160725163759",
    "node": "registry:dt/node#6.0.0+20160831021119"
  }
}
```

And typings/index.d.ts looks like:

```
/// <reference path="globals/d3/index.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="globals/c3/index.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="globals/core-js/index.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="globals/node/index.d.ts" />
```

tsconfig.json looks like:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true
  },
  "files": [
    "typings/index.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

Any clues about what is misconfigured?

Comment: How are you loading your modules?  Are you using SystemJS or Webpack or something else?

Comment: I believe I am using commonJS.  From my tsconfig.json:

`"module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",`

Comment: You are probably using something else to load the individual modules.  That error actually has nothing to do with Typescript, it's failing to load the module itself (which isn't a TS thing).  Can you show your index.html?  That will probably point out what you are using

Comment: ah, I see a `<script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>`

that file is here:
https://gist.github.com/MichaelCPell/d4564b53b25faa3f41e1863e63976006

Comment: You'll probably need to add the module to that.  I haven't used SystemJS in a while, but if I remember right, you'll have to add it to the `map` object and the `packages` object

Comment: You are a hero.  Add answer for points.  New systemjs.config.js:

https://gist.github.com/MichaelCPell/8e76771fc8b8a7ef508281c217ad77a7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using SystemJS you'll need to add the module to the `systemjs.config.js` file (or whatever you called it).  You will need to add the module to the `map` and `pakcages` objects.